# Where is "Test Artifact" on Android Studio 2.2.1

Tags: testing, ui-testing, android-studio-2.2

I created an empty android project on Android Studio 2.2.1, but I can not find the "Test Artifact" in Build Variants. I did nothing, just created an empty project. Why the "Test Artifact" was missing?

> How should I solve it? Thanks in advance.